# Swapping out variables with multiple conditionals in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

this is my reproducible example:

```
SMTscenes.ACC SMTscenes.RESP TrialType 
0             4              Old
0             3              Old
0             r              New
0             2              New
0             1              New
0             r              Old
0             3              Old
```

I'm trying to make an R script that has the following conditions:

If 'SMTscenes.RESP' => 3 or = 'r', AND 'TrialType' = 'Old' then make 'SMTscenes.ACC' = 1

Else, keep it as is.

I tried looking at other questions and how they were answered, but I couldn't implement the functions to mine, particularly because of 'r' not simply being a '5'.

It should look like:

```
SMTscenes.ACC SMTscenes.RESP TrialType 
    1             4              Old
    1             3              Old
    0             r              New
    0             2              New
    0             1              New
    1             r              Old
    1             3              Old
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The following code does what I want:

`df$SMTscenes.ACC <- ifelse(df$SMTscenes.RESP >= '3' & df$TrialType == 'Old', '1', '0')`

Nevertheless, how do I deal with looping it? Overtime I pull my information from a .csv file into a data frame in R, the SMTscenes.RESP column becomes "SMTscenes.RESP1" then "SMTscenes.RESP2" and so on...

Comment: There are many ways but what about simple,  just replacing r with 5 and making it numeric column?

Comment: You can use `?ifelse`.

Comment: So, progress:
 `df$SMTscenes.ACC <- ifelse(df$SMTscenes.RESP >= '3' & df$TrialType == 'Old', '1', '0')` does do what I want, without the need of an extra conditional to take care of the "r" — I guess it just assumes "r" is bigger than or equal to 3....
Now, what if I want to loop this so that It happens for every single instance of SMTscenes.ACC? What I mean by this is that the next series of data (from another participant) is read in R as SMTscenes.ACC1, then SMTscenesACC2, and so on.